# awk to combine files on partial match and append

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to `cp` and `paste` each matching line in `f2` to `$3` in `f1` if `$2` of `f1` is in the line in `f2` somewhere. There will always be a match (usually more then 1) and my actual data is much larger (several hundreds of lines) in both `f1` and `f2`. When the line in `f2` is pasted to `$3` in `f1`, the value in `$1` is appended to it at the end of the line with a `/test/id/$1_raw.file_fixed.txt`. The `$1` value is from `f1` as well. Most of this is static text, except the value from `$1` is after the third `/`. The lines that begin with `R_2019` are just printed as is. The `awk` does execute but the output is unchanged. Thank you :).

I also tried another `awk` with no luck.

**f1**

```
xyxy_0268 0000-yyyy
xyxy_0270 1111-xxxx
R_0000_00_02_00_45_32_xxxx_x0-0000-100-x0.0_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
```

**f2**

```
/path/to/the/xxx/data/0000-yyyy_v1_0000-yyyy_RNA_v1/190326-Control_v1_20190328071906449 
/path/to/the/xxx/data/00-0000_xxxx-03_v1/00-0000_xxxx-03_v1_20190322115521953
/path/to/the/xxx/data/1111-xxxx-03_v1/1111-xxxx-03_v1_20190322115521953
```

**desired**

```
xyxy_0268 0000-yyyy /path/to/the/xxx/data/0000-yyyy_v1_0000-yyyy_RNA_v1/190326-Control_v1_20190328071906449/test/id/xyxy_0268_raw.file_fixed.txt
xyxy_0270 1111-xxxx /path/to/the/xxx/data/1111-xxxx-03_v1/1111-xxxx-03_v1_20190322115521953/test/id/xyxy_0270_raw.file_fixed.txt
R_0000_00_02_00_45_32_xxxx_x0-0000-100-x0.0_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
```

**awk**

```
awk 'NR==FNR {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) id[$i]=$1; next} $2 in id{$3=id[$i] "/test/id/" $1 "_raw.file_fixed.txt"}1' f2 f1

awk 'NR==FNR {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) id[$i]=$1; next} $2 in id{$3=id/$2/ "/test/id/" $1 "_raw.file_fixed.txt"}1' f2 f1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]++; next} {for (i in a) if (i~$2 && $2 != "") {print $0" /test/id/"$2"_raw.file_fixed.txt"; next}} {print}' f2 f1
xyxy_0268 0000-yyyy /test/id/0000-yyyy_raw.file_fixed.txt
xyxy_0270 1111-xxxx /test/id/1111-xxxx_raw.file_fixed.txt
R_0000_00_02_00_45_32_xxxx_x0-0000-100-x0.0_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
```